# Push footer bottom of screen WITHOUT uncessessary scroll

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky

OK, So i've used to common "push" method with the footer to ensure that it stays to the bottom of the page... However, there is now an unnecessary gap between the container and the footer which means that there is always a scroll down, even if there is no content to push it down. I would hope that if there was no content, the footer would just stick nicely to the bottom of the website.

Has anyone else found this and been able to tackle it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with just a few lines of CSS. Assuming that you are using the `<footer>` element, apply the following styling properties:

```
footer {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
```

And that's it!

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
#footer {
position: relative;
left: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
height: 150px; // whatever height you want
width: 100%;
}
```

works for me